# how to remove the new document option in sharepoint.

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have form library in sharepoint 2010. In that library list workflow is associated. Whenever any document is added to 
the library, new document symbol in green color is appearing behind the document.I have googled and got to know that
duration of new document symbol can be reduced or extended using code or command.

My requirement is: First time when document is loaded new document symbol should be there. But when approver approves the document that new document symbol should be disappeared. Is there any way to do this??

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this, I would use jQuery to check the status of the document client side.  If the document is approved, then change the css of the image element so it was no longer displayed (display:none).

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly an answer to you question, but it's worth mentioning that there is an out-of-the-box command allowing to change the number of days the "New" icon is displayed:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -pv 42
```

- [How to stop the !New tag from appearing when you add items to your SharePoint Team Services and SharePoint Services Web site](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;825510)
- [Days-to-show-new-icon: Stsadm property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287681%28office.12%29.aspx)